# Puzzle related to software or technical term

Tags: riddle, treasure-hunt

[image: Help me complete this puzzle related to computers.. mostly technical term or software name will be the answer]

> Try to complete this puzzle
>
> Either a technical term or software name will be the answer.

Comment: Welcome to PSE and congrats on posting your very first question! Do take some time to visit the [help center](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) and get a [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get a badge. By the way, did you get this from another site? If so, then please give a link to it or something. This puzzle also seems to be incomplete (like the zip file which is not shown and the cut rules on your picture). Nevertheless, happy puzzling :D

Comment: Apparently this is the photograph of an e-mail. Can you please reformat your question: copy the **full** text as text (including the rules), add the image as an independent image, add the zip file, etc. Please also specify who created the puzzle. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Partial:

> The first two lines sound to me like [DOS Int21H](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html) because it's Interrupt Request 21.
>  If we convert the numbers 55 45 37 37 to coordinates it points to [Moscow](https://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/?loc=55%2045%27%20N%2037%2037%27%20E&id=1478813#.W45fFs5KiHt) on the map